# Probability that an integer is divisible by $8$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is an integer from $1$ to $96$ (inclusive), what is the probability that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by 8?

Comment: Hint: if $n$ is even, then $8\mid n(n+1)(n+2)$ (it's not obvious, think why this is so). For $n$ odd, can $n$ and $n+2$ contribute a factor of 2? When can $n+1$ make the number divisible by 8?

Comment: @Wojowu Your comment posted like 10 seconds before my answer, sorry about that. +1 on your comment.

Comment: @user2566092 That's no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $n+1$ is even, then both $n$ and $n+2$ are odd so the only hope is that $n+1$ is divisible by $8$. If $n+1$ is odd, then can you see why your expression is always divisible by 8?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the product is divisible by $8$ if:

- One factor is divisible by 8, or
- One factor is divisible by 4 and another is divisible by 2, or
- All three factors are divisible by 2.

The last one is impossible in your situation (why?) What are the possible remainders when $n$ is divided by $8$ such that the first and second possibilities occur?

Answer (score 0):

If n is from
1 to 96,
it is divisible by 8
if it is of the form
8m+k
where
k = 0, 2, 4, 6, or 7.
There are
5(96/8) = 60
from 1 to 96.

Therefore the probability is
60/96 = 5/8.